# Getting java execution ,error while trying to install Hadoop single node cluster

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I'm getting the same error as mentioned while running Hadoop.
I've only user level access not root access of the complete Linux machine.
Is there any solution  ?? Any help will be really appreciated.TIA :) 
Linux plateform : redhat linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5))

```
[aa86980@HMLINUX1 hadoop-1.2.1]$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
bin/hadoop: line 350: /home/aa86980/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
bin/hadoop: line 434: /home/aa86980/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
bin/hadoop: line 434: /home/aa86980/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java: Success
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 sudo bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: I don't have SUDO access :(